# Virtualize Android on arm64 with qemu

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, qemu, arm64, lineageos

I'm new to the forum and am currently working on virtualizing Android on a Raspi4.

The crux of the matter is that the Raspi has an ARM processor and therefore seems well suited for Android.

Now I have compiled Lineage according to the instructions for arm https://wiki.lineageos.org/emulator
I used a Linux computer with AMD for this.

I just want to start it directly with qemu in order to be able to control how many instances of it are running. With the emulator command I don't get any further either, since the 200GB of repo and all of the other data are not on the Raspi.

I've pulled the kernel 5.4 and the system.img over, which is in / home / android / lineage / out / target / product / generic_arm64 and am now trying to get it to work somehow. Unfortunately I get the message from qemu-system-aarch64 that the root file system cannot be mounted with the current command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt,accel=kvm -cpu host -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/ panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 loglevel=8 rw" -drive "file=system.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw" -kernel kernel-5.4
```

I tried many paths like root=/dev/sda0 sda1 vda...

```
[    0.651008] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    0.651754] 0100            8192 ram0
[    0.651755]  (driver?)
[    0.652319] 0101            8192 ram1
[    0.652319]  (driver?)
[    0.652891] 0102            8192 ram2
[    0.652891]  (driver?)
[    0.653511] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    0.654294] platform regulatory.0: Falling back to sysfs fallback for: regulatory.db
[    0.655023] 0103            8192 ram3
[    0.655024]  (driver?)
[    0.655587] 0104            8192 ram4
[    0.655587]  (driver?)
[    0.656154] 0105            8192 ram5
[    0.656155]  (driver?)
[    0.656716] 0106            8192 ram6
[    0.656717]  (driver?)
[    0.657310] 0107            8192 ram7
[    0.657311]  (driver?)
[    0.657885] 0108            8192 ram8
[    0.657885]  (driver?)
[    0.658446] 0109            8192 ram9
[    0.658446]  (driver?)
[    0.659010] 010a            8192 ram10
[    0.659010]  (driver?)
[    0.659578] 010b            8192 ram11
[    0.659579]  (driver?)
[    0.660154] 010c            8192 ram12
[    0.660154]  (driver?)
[    0.660732] 010d            8192 ram13
[    0.660733]  (driver?)
[    0.661102] kworker/u2:0 (102): highest shadow stack usage: 144 bytes
[    0.661917] cryptomgr_probe (104): highest shadow stack usage: 168 bytes
[    0.662536] 010e            8192 ram14
[    0.662536]  (driver?)
[    0.663116] 010f            8192 ram15
[    0.663117]  (driver?)
[    0.663689] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Do any of you have an idea or approach how to get all of this working?

Thanks and regards,

Hal